# Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to do the same thing as in this amazing video of Dan Abramov 
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-redux-passing-the-store-down-with-provider-from-react-redux
but i got the following error : Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined.
Here is the first part of my code where i'm using the provider, i use [Component].contextTypes and the PropTypes npm package in order to fill the context with the store.

```js
const render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={createStore(my_global_todo)}>
            <Rendertodo />
        </Provider >
        , document.getElementById('root')
    );
};
```

I've got something like 4 errors pages, every one from a line where i'm using the store.
I don't understand why this is not working, can any one learn to me how this is working ?
Here is a sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-glitter-60gx5?fontsize=14

Comment: Can you supply a codesandbox or something similar of your project? It's going to be really hard to help without a way to reproduce the error.

Comment: Here is a sandbox link : https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-glitter-60gx5?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using legacy context api which is deprecated, a possible fix to continue with the course is to change `react-redux` version to 5.1.1, so you can access the store using the legacy context api

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-gauss-lxcky